# pkg 'make' error while installing control package in GNU - Octave 6.2.0

Tags: linux, octave, oct2py

I am trying to install the signal package, which in turn requires the control packge. However, I am getting the following error when trying to install the control package on the octave terminal:

```
octave:2> pkg install -forge signal
error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied:
   signal needs control >= 2.4
octave:3> pkg install -forge control
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=11.4'
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=11.4'
make: *** [slicotlibrary.a] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
tar -xzf slicot.tar.gz
/usr/local/Cellar/octave/6.2.0_3/bin/mkoctfile-6.2.0 -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations  __control_helper_functions__.cc
mkdir sltmp
mv slicot/src/*.f ./sltmp
mv slicot/src_aux/*.f ./sltmp
if [ "0" = "1" ]; then \
        echo "copy routines using DGGES"; \
        cp SB04OD.fortran ./sltmp/SB04OD.f; \
        cp SG03AD.fortran ./sltmp/SG03AD.f; \
        cp SG03BD.fortran ./sltmp/SG03BD.f; \
    fi;
cp AB08NX.fortran ./sltmp/AB08NX.f
cp AG08BY.fortran ./sltmp/AG08BY.f
cp SB01BY.fortran ./sltmp/SB01BY.f
cp SB01FY.fortran ./sltmp/SB01FY.f
cp SB06ND.fortran ./sltmp/SB06ND.f
cp TB01MD.fortran ./sltmp/TB01MD.f
cp TB01ND.fortran ./sltmp/TB01ND.f
cp TB01ZD.fortran ./sltmp/TB01ZD.f
cp TG04BX.fortran ./sltmp/TG04BX.f
cp ODLTZM.fortran ./sltmp/ODLTZM.f
cp makefile.slicot ./sltmp/makefile
cd sltmp; /usr/local/Cellar/octave/6.2.0_3/bin/mkoctfile-6.2.0 -w -c MA02ID.f; rm MA02ID.f; /usr/local/Cellar/octave/6.2.0_3/bin/mkoctfile-6.2.0 -c *.f;

error: pkg: error running 'make' for the control package.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 110 column 9
    install at line 196 column 7
    pkg at line 568 column 9
```

I have searched up the error and looked through some other posts but haven't been able to figure out a solution to this - can anyone advise me on what might be the issue here? Thanks!

Comment: The error: `clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=11.4'`. So the problem is that your C compiler is being invoked with an argument it doesn't accept. Might need to be updated. Or figure out how to tell the package's configuration script to not try to use that option.

Comment: Some quick searching shows that is a common issue. The error also strongly suggests you're using a Mac, not a linux system, so why tag this linux?

Comment: My apologies for the linux tagging, I hadn't removed it when it was tagged to my post after writing it. I was able to update my C compiler accordingly to get the installations to work, thanks so much for nudging me in the right direction!